# Posts of custom post type load the page template

Tags: custom-post-types, single

I make a custom post type named "event". The weird thing is when I visit a post in this type, it shows the archive-event template. If there's no `archieve-event.php` file, it loads the page template.

I put the `single-event.php` file in the root directory of the theme(it should display "single event"), but obviously the system ignored it.

I make the custom post type by:

```
register_post_type('event', 
        array(
            'labels'                        => PW_get_post_type_label('活动'),
            'public'                            => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus'     => false,
            'show_in_admin_bar'     => false,
            'menu_position'         => 5,
            'capability_type'       => array('event','events'),
            'map_meta_cap'          => true,
            'supports'              => array('title','editor','thumbnail','comments'),
            'taxonomies'                => array('event_category'),
            'has_archive'                   => true,
            'rewrite'               => array('slug' => 'event'),
            'publicly_queryable'    => true,
            )
        );
```

there're two pieces of code about the link and rewrite rules

```
add_filter('post_type_link', 'PW_custom_post_type_link', 1, 3);
function PW_custom_post_type_link( $link, $post = 0 ){
    if ( $post->post_type == 'event' ){
        return home_url( 'event/' . $post->ID );
    } else {
        return $link;
    }
}

add_action( 'init', 'PW_custom_post_rewrites_init' );
function PW_custom_post_rewrites_init(){
    add_rewrite_rule( 'event/([0-9]+)?$', 'index.php?post_type=event&p=$matches[1]', 'top' );
}
```

the post's link is like dev.photoworld.com.cn/event/POST-ID

Answer (score 2):

OK, done. That's because I need to refresh the permalink option in the Admin menu. Every time you change the rewrite or link thing, you need to go to the "Options->Permalink" and save it again.